# How to add a Lotus Notes TO-DO entry with C#?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I'm creating a small application from which users can send mails, appointments and to-do items to lotus notes. I was able to find a way to send appointments to lotus notes using the following method which I found out from the web.

```
Domino.NotesSession LNSession = new Domino.NotesSession();
Domino.NotesDatabase LNDatabase;
Domino.NotesDocument LNDocument;

try
{
   LNSession.Initialize("password");
   LNDatabase = LNSession.GetDatabase("my lotus mail server", @"location\dbfilename", false);

   LNDocument = LNDatabase.CreateDocument();
   LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Appointment");
   ...
}
```

now I want to send To-Do items but could not find sample on the web.
     LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Appointment");
I think I just need the value that I need to replace (as ***"Appointment"*** for sending calendar items for To-Do items ?) and also the attributes of Lotus Notes To-Do items.

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the document properties of a ToDo you can see that the form is "Task". All the items on the document/todo can be investigated there. After adding the Form item, run a `ComputeWithForm` this will set some of the attributes.

**ComputeWithForm**
Validates a document by executing the default value, translation, and validation formulas, if any are defined in the document form.
Syntax: flag = notesDocument.ComputeWithForm( doDataTypes, raiseError )